# What is the difference between these two ICs?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Is there a difference between these two ICs, or are they the same?

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC4049.pdf

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4049.pdf

Comment: Just different manufacturers.

Comment: make sure that you get the package you want - these parts are probably avaialble in both through-hole and surface mount packages.

Answer (score 4):

They're two versions of the same standard part made by two different manufacturers (NXP and TI, respectively). Some of the detailed specifications may differ slightly, but generally speaking these parts will be fully interchangeable.

Answer (score -1):

to short answer no.. 
but if you get into details (look into max temperature) for example. they differ slightly but usually it doesnt matter
look at this: EEVblog #1057 - µCurrent Murphy

Comment: when you vote down a guy, please tell him why so he knows.. :)